# Rails Single Table Inheritance how to find record of child classes from querying parent class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have `events` table and `Event` class which supports Single Table Inheritance.
There is `Events::Template` class inheriting from it. And there are more 3-4 classes which inherits from this `Events::Template` class (i.e. 3 tier inheritance).

When I query on `Events::Template` class I want the result records of all child classes. so when i do

```
Events::Template.where(....)
```

it generates following query

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE "events"."type" IN ('Events::Template')...
```

This default query filters the type to `Events::Template` only.

Is there any way I can remove the default query of type or change it to look in to all child classes of `Events::Template`?

Comment: STI don't support what you are looking for, AFAIK. You need to change your architecture..

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can remember you need to put addition field in your table (events) - type:string

you can use this field to filter your query.

Comment: field is there... the issue is when I write scope in parent class it is filtering the result by `type` as mentioned in question. So is there a way to remove/modify this default filter?

Comment: I just read the question again and I need some explanation: your template class is: 
Template
and you have following children:
Event::Template
SomethingElese::Template
?

maybe the singular vs plural is the issue ?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, the relation is as following

Event => Events::Template => (1. Events::Template::Create 2. Events::Template::Delete 3. Events::Template::Update)

Comment: so `Event` is the top most class... `Events::Template` is it's child and other three classes are children of `Events::Template` class

Comment: I'm not sure why you use STI in in your situation. I'm curious what is the logic behind "Create", "Delete" and "Update" children classes. :) Are you sure what you're looking for can not be solved with state machine or service objects? Either way I will quickly have a look if i can help you with this

Comment: OK, I just tried. All works like a charm: 

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Event::Template < Event
end

class Event::Template::Create < Event::Template
end

(I use singular everywhere. Rails sometimes complains if you add plural)

Event::Template.where.not(name: nil)

this will only return children, not the instances of Event

Comment: this generates:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" WHERE "events"."type" IN ('Event::Template', 'Event::Template::Delete', 'Event::Template::Create') AND ("events"."name" IS NOT NULL)

Comment: Cool thanks.. I think i should stick to singular name spaces... Though one concern... using `Event::Template` will create a module named `Event` right?? cause I already have a class named `Event`.

Comment: In above setup there are no modules, just models